# .tofixed(2) not working when substracting a result?

Tags: javascript, html

How can i substract the result i get from x without loosing a decimal place in an html input box??

So, lets say i have x=40.40 and i substract 25, the result should be 15.40 and i am getting 15.4 without that zero. How can i prevent loosing that extra decimal, if i necesarily want to substract that 25 without altering anything else?? (For y i get a 0 with no decimal places and i need 0.00)

```
document.getElementById("posx").value=(x.toFixed(2)-25.00);
document.getElementById("posy").value=(y1.toFixed(2)-(-2.45));
```

Comment: It's "subtract" not "substract".

Comment: @Pointy yeah haha :), didnt notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to `toFixed` it after the subtraction

```
document.getElementById("posx").value = (x - 25.00).toFixed(2);
```

`toFixed` converts the value to a string, as numbers don't have zero padding, only the decimals needed to correctly reflect the value of the number.

When you subtract a number from a string, you end up with a number, and as numbers only have the needed decimals, no zero padding, you get `15.4`, and once again have to use `toFixed` to convert it to a string with the decimals you need.

Comment: Thx, that worked. I didnt know why I couldnt keep the two decimal places after subtracting.